# Fine uploader delete link

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I am using Fine uploader, ajax uploader with image preview. I am not using Fine Uploader Basic mode.

How can i move delete link

```
<a class="qq-upload-delete" href="#" style="display: inline;">Delete</a>
```

from `<ul class="qq-upload-list">` to `<li id="thumb">` which is surrounding the image.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#thumbnail-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
      request: {
        endpoint: 'includes/example.php'
      },
        deleteFile: {
        enabled: true,
        forceConfirm: true
      },
      multiple: false,
      validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
        sizeLimit: 51200 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
      },
      text: {
        uploadButton: 'Dodajte sliku',
        deleteButton: ' '
      }
    }).on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {

        if (responseJSON.success) {
          $(this).append('<li id="thumb"><img src="img/success.jpg" alt="' + fileName + '"></li>');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I want to achieve this so there is a delete link next to every image and not in upload list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-parenting the delete link is probably not going to work here, due to the way the file item delete anchor functions.

Instead, why not create your own delete button?  Your `complete` callback handler could look something like this:

```
.on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, response) {
   if (response.success) {
       var $deleteEl = $('<a href="#">Delete</a>');

      //when you delete element is clicked, call the "deleteFile" API method, passing in that file's ID
      $deleteEl.click(function() {
         $('#thumbnail-fine-uploader').fineUploader('deleteFile', id);
      });

      $(this).append('<li id="thumb"><img src="img/success.jpg" alt="' + fileName + '"></li>')
             .append($deleteEl);
   }
});
```

Of course, you can adjust the delete anchor HTML to suit your application's style.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Complete callback handler doesn't show thumbnail and delete link, and when this 
      $deleteEl.click(function() {
         $('#thumbnail-fine-uploader').fineUploader('deleteFile', id);
      });

is moved after $(this).append('<li id="thumb"><img src="img/success.jpg" alt="' + fileName + '"></li>')
             .append($deleteEl); it shows thumbnail with delete link, but shows an error in console ([FineUploader] Caught exception in 'onComplete' callback - Object <a href="#">Delete</a> has no method 'click' )

Comment: The "has no method"issue should be fixed in my latest edit above.  I had a typo on the $delete var declaration by forgetting to make that a jquery object.